# Sacar datos de una tabla

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
Select ae.Expe , n1.Nom, ae.DtAlt
  from aExpe ae (nolock)  
left join bPersCarac bPers (nolock)
on bpers.IdExpe = ae.IdExpe
left join NProblematicas1 n1 (nolock)
on n1.id = bpers.IdProblematica2
where ae.idCodine ='2512070005' and n1.nom is null 
and ae.DtAlt   BETWEEN  '01/06/2020 00:00:00.000' and   '31/12/2021 00:00:00.000'
```

Haciendo esta consulta saco todos los expedientes que tienen problemáticas y hasta aquí todo bien. El problema es que necesito todos los expedientes que no existan en la tabla bpersCarac..

Con esto lo que hago es sacar los que si que están en bPersCarac pero lo que necesito es justo lo contrario, como puedo hacer para listar todos los expedientes y excluir todos los que salen en bpersCarac?

gracias!

Comment: Las respuestas que hay hasta ahora apuntan en la dirección correcta. Sin embargo, para preguntas sobre BD, procura indicar la estructura de las tablas que usas, algún dato de prueba y la salida esperada para que te ayuden _mejor_ y más rápido :)

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Cómo puedo hacer para listar todos los expedientes y excluir todos
> los que salen en `bpersCarac`?

Lo clásico es una estructura que se conoce como "anti join", mediante el uso del `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT ae.Expe
       FROM aExpe ae
       WHERE ae.IdExpe NOT IN (SELECT IdExpe FROM bPersCarac)
```

Ahora, en el contexto de tu consulta, también puedes hacer:

```
SELECT ae.Expe,
       ae.DtAlt
       FROM aExpe ae
       LEFT JOIN join bPersCarac bPers
            on bpers.IdExpe = ae.IdExpe
       WHERE ae.idCodine ='2512070005' 
             and bpers.IdExpe is null
             and ae.DtAlt BETWEEN '01/06/2020' and '31/12/2021'
```

En este caso:

- La condición para determinar lo que no existen es `and bpers.IdExpe is null`
- No tiene sentido usar la tabla `NProblematicas1`, porque al no haber coincidencias en `bPersCarac` tampoco las habrá en `NProblematicas1`

Answer (score 1):

Con **LEFT JOIN** vas a sacar **todos** los registros de la primera tabla (aExpe), aunque no estén en las relacionadas. Pero si no están en  bPersCarac obtendrás en bpers.IdExpe es NULL, por tanto puedes añadir al where la condición de que isNull(bpers.IdExpe), los que no tienen correspondencia en esta tabla.
Pienso que es una solución, aún sin ver la tabla ni su estructura.

Comment: La función isnull requiere al menos 2 argumentos. ?? no acabo de entender la parte del where sorry

Comment: Por lo que yo se la función de MySQL isNull(expr) solo usa un argumento, si ese argumento es null devuelve 1 (true) y si no devuelve 0 (false). Y lo de añdir la condición a where se debe a que los elementos de la tabla primera (left) que **no están en la segunda** tendrán como valor del campo que las relaciona el valor NULL para esta segunda tabla.